# Windows Vista Stuck on Welcome page; focus stolen, by what?

Tags: windows-vista

My father in-law presented me with a highly unusual problem: his Windows Vista machine suddenly could not log in: he was greeted with the usual Welcome Screen, the mouse responded , but nothing happened when you clicked on the avatars (other than the background highlighting changing, suggesting it was selected but not clicked). I was stumped. A bit of research suggested that something was stealing focus from the welcome screen. Unbelievable that this could happen, but sure enough pressing Alt+Tab and then using the mouse normally worked fine (or using tab and then pressing Enter).

The problem occurs when I boot in safe mode and when I disable all non-microsoft services and most startup items in msconfig.

I want to *know* what this pop-up is? Is there a way to do this? There are solutions out there for this problem (repair/restore/etc) but I think they are inelegant and I am dying to know what it is (my prime suspect was something called Norton Identity Safe, which had a corrupt install but I think I finally got it removed and it is still happening)

Comment: This sounds more like malware.  If those solutions exist to this problem why have you not tried those before asking this question the community will likely suggest those same solutions you have not already tried.

Comment: Is this a laptop? I've seen weird stuff like this happen with badly written fingerprint identification software that allows for an alternate login method on that screen.

Comment: Desktop. I built it years ago. The system is up to date and has MSE installed (and at least had some Norton scan). The owner does not do much with the machine, so I am pretty sure it is not Malware (and if it is, I would like to confirm and identify the Malware rather than guess...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I solved the problem, though I don't think my solution was completely satisfactory (and, because I was in a hurry, I tried two solutions, so I am not sure which one actually worked).

1. I used sysinternals [autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to truly remove all references to that Norton program (that, in spite of uninstalling, were still there) from running.
2. I used [sfc.exe](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833) (which identified a problem and fixed it) to repair system files

After doing the above actions, I restarted the computer and was able to log in to Windows with mouse-press alone. I would still select an answer that showed me how I can know if there are (and what are) any active windows outside the login context (I am still surprised and skeptical that this could happen) over and above my own answer.

P.S. I did look at the event log and found a couple of suspect events, but they all led me down the garden path.